# ZingTouch prevents user to enter words into the input field

Tags: javascript

[ZingTouch is a JavaScript touch gesture detection library for the modern web.](https://github.com/zingchart/zingtouch)

After I started using it, I could not enter words into my input fields anymore.

*CodePen Example with the same problem:* Link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMVXyQ

My **input field** looks like this:

```
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
   <input type="text" name="praeferenz" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="..." aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
   <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">-Utilitarismus</span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

This **GIF** shows how the input field works without ZingTouch:

[image]

After I added Zingtouch, I cannot enter any words into the input field anymore.

This **GIF** shows how I can't click into the field:

[image]

Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
//zingtouch
var touchArea = document.body;
var myRegion = new ZingTouch.Region(touchArea);

myRegion.bind(touchArea, 'swipe', function(e){
  if(90 < e.detail.data[0].currentDirection && e.detail.data[0].currentDirection < 270){
    console.log("LEFT SWIPE");
    getNextSlide();
  } else{
    console.log("RIGHT SWIPE");
    getPreviousSlide();
  }
});
```

**Question:**

Is there a way for me to have both, ZingTouch and the ability to enter words into the input field?

**Things I noticed:**

1. I still can click on buttons. All my buttons work as expected.
2. When I click anywhere on the page `'style="touch-action: none;"'` gets added to `"body"`.

**What I tried so far:**

I tried to use another region.

Instead of document.body, I created a div with an ID and used that as the region:

```
var touchArea = document.getElementById('yield');
var myRegion = new ZingTouch.Region(touchArea);
```

But the problem remained.

**CodePen Example**

The following CodePen demonstrates the same problem.

It's not possible to click into the input fields.

Link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMVXyQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ZingTouch.Region` has a third parameter `preventDefault` that can be used to turn of this behaviour.

like:

`const zt = new ZingTouch.Region(document.body, undefined, false)`

`const zt = new ZingTouch.Region(element, capture, preventDefault)`

> - element - The element to set the listener upon
> - capture - Whether the region listens for captures or bubbles.
> - preventDefault - Disables browser functionality such as scrolling and zooming over the region.

See https://github.com/zingchart/zingtouch#region

After turning `preventDefault` to `false` it is possible to e.g. listen on document events and using input fields below. Normally zingtouch adds `touch-action: none;` to the style of the element, this prevents the interaction.